# CKModifyRecordsOperation saves an Child record without parent

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, synchronization, cloudkit

I am trying to implement a local cache of cloudkit records. It is mentioned in the doc that “During a save operation, CloudKit verifies that any target records actually exist in the database. If it cannot verify the existence of a target record, CloudKit reports an error and does not save the record containing the reference to that target. ”  But its not working that way, it saves the child record without throwing any error.

Now in this scenario if I follow the below steps for syncing.

1. Fetch local changes
2. Upload the local changes to cloud
3. Correct the conflicts if any
4. Fetch server changes
5. Apply server changes to local

The database can get corrupted for following senario.

1. Say D1 , D2 and cloud are in sync with 1 Child and 1 Parent record
2. Now on D1 device delete both the parent and Child and sync with cloud. Hence on both D1 and Cloud the child and parent record are deleted.
3. On D2 we add a new child record now we sync what happens here is New Child is uploaded and its parent and the old child record is deleted, hence am left with a child with no parent.  both on cloud and on D2 device.

I am creating a reference in following way

```
    CKRecord *newRecord = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType:ReferenceSubItemsRecordType];
    newRecord[NameField] = self.nameTextField.text;
    newRecord[ParentField] =[[CKReference alloc] initWithRecordID:self.parentRecordID action:CKReferenceActionDeleteSelf];
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why am I not getting an error for above situation?

Comment: You are trying to chain multiple database operations one after the other, but they run asynchronously. Are you sure that each step runs to completion before the next starts?

Comment: yes am sure that they run only after the previous is completed.

Comment: Possible dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891878/cloudkit-sync-with-coredata-issue-with-ckmodifyoperation?rq=1

Comment: I don't think CloudKit considers this an error. In the WWDC talks, they tell you to expect to handle dangling references.