# Cloudkit Sync With CoreData Issue with CKModifyOperation

Tags: database, core-data, cloud, synchronization, cloudkit

Am trying to sync cloudkit and coredata. Have two tables as:

1. Parent
2. Child (Child has a CKReference to Parent. i.e Backward reference from child to parent.)

Now according to apple this are the steps we must follow.

1. Fetch local changes - Done by maintaining a update variable with every record. say 3-delete, 1-create and 2-update.
2. Upload the local changes to cloud - Here I use CKModifyRecordsOperation and provide the inserted records as one with update value 1 or 3 and 2 as deleted records. (Atomic to avoid inconsistency)
3. Correct the conflicts if any (So here records with greater modification date are chosen and conflicts are resolved.)
4. Fetch server changes (Here any change that are made to server from last change token are fetched with CKFetchChangesOperation)
5. Apply server changes to local()

Now say I have 2 devices and have already synced them with following data

1. Parent-1
2. P1-Child1 (references Parent-1)

Now in 1 device I delete Parent-1 and P1-Child1 and let it sync to cloud.   On cloudkit dashboard i verify that the Parent and child both have been successfully deleted.

In Device 2, Now I add P1-Child2 another child to previous parent. Consider the above steps

1. LocalChanges :- (P1-Child2)
2. Upload to cloud :- (P1-Child2)
3. Conflicts :- None
4. Fetch changes from cloud :(Inserted :P1-Child2, Deleted:Parent-1,P1-Child1)
5. Apply this to local.

P1-Child2 is saved successfully on Cloud without a parent. So now am left with a child record with no parent.

Can you guys help me in figuring out the right method to solve this. 
I thought if apple could have given an error on CKModifyOperation as mentioned in its doc then I could know that a parent record does not exist and I can re-save or upload a parent record along with the child.

Comment: So you are saying that saving this new Child2 to CK works despite the fact that the parent it is referencing is no longer on CK? Are you sure you are getting no error in this operation?

Comment: Yes sir, am not getting any error while saving the child2

Comment: in that case this seems to me like a CK bug. Try to file a bug report with Apple

Comment: Yes sir, did ask for TSI but its taking time so in meanwhile needed to find a solution that could work. I searched at many forums but no one seems to have this problem so was thinking am I the only one facing the problem.

Comment: One comment when I think about it. Are you aware that Apple recommendation is to first fetch the latest from the CK server and only then save your local changes? I think if you change the order you do things it could circumvent the issue

Comment: Yes sir, actually in advance cloudkit WWDC session 231 suggests following "The first thing you're going to want to do in your app is to track the local changes. Then, you're going to need to send all those changes up to the server.
You want to do that before you fetch the changes because someone else might have changed the record in the meantime, and you need to resolve these conflicts."